# Time difference between First Call time and First Order Time from Call table and Order table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables, 'Call' and 'Order, and trying to get the Time difference between 'First Call' time and 'First Order' Time from the Call table and Order table, please see the attached example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below SQL to see if it helps:

```
create or replace table call_table (key varchar, call_time timestamp);
create or replace table order_table (key varchar, order_time timestamp);

insert into call_table values 
('key_1', '2021-09-04 10:10:00'),
('key_1', '2021-09-04 10:14:00'),
('key_2', '2021-09-04 10:17:00'),
('key_2', '2021-09-04 10:18:00'),
('key_2', '2021-09-04 10:19:00'),
('key_2', '2021-10-01 11:20:00');

insert into order_table values 
('key_1', '2021-09-04 10:15:00'),
('key_1', '2021-09-04 10:18:00'),
('key_1', '2021-09-04 10:19:00'),
('key_2', '2021-09-04 10:22:00'),
('key_2', '2021-09-04 10:23:00'),
('key_2', '2021-09-04 10:24:00');


with my_call as (
  select key, min(call_time) as first_time
  from call_table
  group by key
),
my_order as (
  select key, min(order_time) as first_time
  from order_table
  group by key
)
select 
  c.key, 
  c.first_time, 
  o.first_time, 
  datediff('min', c.first_time, o.first_time) as time_diff
from my_call c
join my_order o ON (c.key = o.key);
```

Comment: Thanks, Eric Lin, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Glad that it helps John!